# Unicorns enter a restart loop on Heroku

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2, unicorn

I have a rails application deployed to Heroku Celadon cedar stack using Unicorn (4.5.0) with the following unicorn.rb file:

```
worker_processes 2 # amount of unicorn workers to spin up
timeout 30         # restarts workers that hang for 30 seconds
check_client_connection true
```

At seemingly random times without any noticable change in services it uses(including DB) unicorns will enter a restart loop. They will keep restarting with the following typical error:

```
ERROR -- : worker=0 PID:935 timeout (31s > 30s), killing
```

The problem is that is keeps restarting more often than every 30 seconds per unicorn worker. It stops when the underlying dyno gets restarted so I'm guessing it has something to do with the way unicorn master process and heroku interact.

Anyone else experiencing this or has any ideas as to what could be the cause?

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the `check_client_connection true` option.

According to Heroku Unicorn [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-unicorn) you should use a configuration file like this:

```
# config/unicorn.rb
worker_processes 3
timeout 15
preload_app true

before_fork do |server, worker|

  Signal.trap 'TERM' do
    puts 'Unicorn master intercepting TERM and sending myself QUIT instead'
    Process.kill 'QUIT', Process.pid
  end

  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
end  

after_fork do |server, worker|

  Signal.trap 'TERM' do
    puts 'Unicorn worker intercepting TERM and doing nothing. Wait for master to send QUIT'
  end

  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

Comment: Can you explain why you think that check_client_connection is the culprit? 

The before and after fork callbacks are there mostly because of preload_app set to true. I've had that before but I switched back to preload_app false because I was experiencing some unrelated issues. 
check_client_connection is a relatively new option and from the unicorn documentation it should be safe to turn on.

Comment: The documentation states that this only works on unix domain sockets and the loopback interface. I believe Heroku doesn't use a local webserver installation as this won't scale well ;-)